# Editing Array Elements - Remove Character and Subtract 1

Tags: arrays, bash, element

I have an array which has two elements that are not useful in their current state, I need to remove a character and subtract one from them.

I have tried to strip the character so that I can put the number into an equation but it doesn't seem to save my new characterless elements into a variable.

```
array=(ab cd C5 ef gh R6 0.88)

#get rid of C
RemChar="${array[2]}" | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'
#subtract 1 from 5
NewValue=(($RemoveChar-1))
#Replace Old Element
${array[2]}=NewValue

#get rid of R
RemChar="${array[5]}" | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'
#subtract 1 from 6
NewValue=(($RemoveChar-1))
#Replace Old Element
${array[5]}=NewValue

#Now the new array 'should' be:
array=(ab cd 4 ef gh 5 0.88)
```

However, it never gets off the ground. Whilst this works:

```
echo "${array[2]}" | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'
```

This does not:

```
RemChar="${array[2]}" | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'
echo "$RemChar"
```

I'm obviously not grasping how to strip characters and put these in a new variable.

Comment: How to identify which element to add and which to subtract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a specific element,

```
echo $(( ${array[2]#C} - 1 )) # explicitly remove C
4
echo $(( ${array[2]#?} - 1 )) # explicitly remove *any* first character
4
echo $(( ${array[2]//[a-zA-Z]/} - 1 )) # # explicitly remove all letters
4
```

...but manually selecting the element seems odd unless that's just your data structure.
How about a loop?

```
array=(ab cd C5 ef gh R6 0.88) # create the array

for ndx in "${!array[@]}" # loop over the indexes, 0-6
do if [[ "${array[ndx]}" =~ [[:alpha:]] ]] && # if there's a letter
      [[ "${array[ndx]}" =~ [[:digit:]] ]]    # AND a digit
   then # scrub the letter(s) and decrement the digit, 
        # assign the result over the original value.
        array[ndx]="$(( ${array[ndx]//[[:alpha:]]/} - 1 ))" 
   fi
done

declare -p array # show the new result set
```

Output:

```
declare -a array=([0]="ab" [1]="cd" [2]="4" [3]="ef" [4]="gh" [5]="5" [6]="0.88")
```

Comment: Thank you your answer and also for making it wonderfully clear!

Answer (score 1):

In

```
RemChar="${array[2]}" | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'
```

you are not doing what you expect. Compare it with your working version:

```
echo "${array[2]}" | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'
```

Here you are running `echo` to give an input to `sed`. In the first line, nothing is given to `sed`.

You are also expecting to substitute the result of the execution for its value to store it in the var. For this, you should use a command substitution syntax:

```
RemChar=$(echo "${array[2]}" | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g')
```

And this line is also an example of a Useless Use Of Echo. It would be cleaner with a *here string*:

```
RemChar=$(sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g' <<< "${array[2]}")
```

You can even avoid the use of `sed` by using the facilities provided by bash:

```
RemChar="${array[2]//[A-Za-z]/}"
```

The pattern is the same you used with a `/` added at the beginning to tell `bash` to substitute all matches in the string (mimmicking your `g` in `sed`).